# could not find ZenTest-4.11.0 in any any of the source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a probleme whith gem ZenTest, i don't have ZenTest in my gemfile, and when i wante generate a integration test whith " rails generate integration_test layout link" i have this error :

```
could not find ZenTest-4.11.0 in any any of the source
```

so i tried `bundle install` and `bundle update` but nothing change,I also tried to install ZenTest and i still have the same mistake

gemefile.lock:

```
specs:
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.7)
  actionpack (= 3.0.7)
  mail (~> 2.2.15)
actionpack (3.0.7)
  activemodel (= 3.0.7)
  activesupport (= 3.0.7)
  builder (~> 2.1.2)
  erubis (~> 2.6.6)
  i18n (~> 0.5.0)
  rack (~> 1.2.1)
  rack-mount (~> 0.6.14)
  rack-test (~> 0.5.7)
  tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
activemodel (3.0.7)
  activesupport (= 3.0.7)
  builder (~> 2.1.2)
  i18n (~> 0.5.0)
activerecord (3.0.7)
  activemodel (= 3.0.7)
  activesupport (= 3.0.7)
  arel (~> 2.0.2)
  tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
activeresource (3.0.7)
  activemodel (= 3.0.7)
  activesupport (= 3.0.7)
activesupport (3.0.7)
annotate (2.4.0)
arel (2.0.10)
builder (2.1.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.6.6)
  abstract (>= 1.0.0)
i18n (0.5.4)
mail (2.2.20)
  activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
  i18n (>= 0.4.0)
  mime-types (~> 1.16)
  treetop (~> 1.4.8)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
  mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.2.8)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
  rack (>= 1.0.0)
rack-test (0.5.7)
  rack (>= 1.0)
rails (3.0.7)
  actionmailer (= 3.0.7)
  actionpack (= 3.0.7)
  activerecord (= 3.0.7)
  activeresource (= 3.0.7)
  activesupport (= 3.0.7)
  bundler (~> 1.0)
  railties (= 3.0.7)
railties (3.0.7)
  actionpack (= 3.0.7)
  activesupport (= 3.0.7)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  thor (~> 0.14.4)
rake (11.1.2)
rspec (2.5.0)
  rspec-core (~> 2.5.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 2.5.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 2.5.0)
rspec-core (2.5.2)
rspec-expectations (2.5.0)
  diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
rspec-mocks (2.5.0)
rspec-rails (2.5.0)
  actionpack (~> 3.0)
  activesupport (~> 3.0)
  railties (~> 3.0)
  rspec (~> 2.5.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.15)
  polyglot
  polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
tzinfo (0.3.48)
webrat (0.7.1)
  nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)
  rack (>= 1.0)
  rack-test (>= 0.5.3)
```

DEPENDENCIES

```
 annotate (= 2.4.0)


 rails (= 3.0.7)



rake (= 11.1.2)



rspec (= 2.5.0)



 rspec-rails (= 2.5.0)



sqlite3
  webrat (= 0.7.1)
```

Comment: Is `ZenTest` gem a dependency of some other gem or you are explicitly adding and using it yourself?

Comment: I would not install it, I use rspec and since I have this message

Comment: According to your `Gemfile.lock`,  there is no dependency on ZenTest gem. It does not look like you added ZenTest as your dependency, but then again why are you getting that error then!? Please add full stack trace here.

Answer (score 0):

You are answering your own question, aren't you? Or, did you mean something else?

> i don't have ZenTest in my gemfile

Well, add it then!

```
# In your Gemfile
gem 'ZenTest'
```

Then do `bundle install`.

**Update:** Looking into the screenshot, it seems that your Gemfile is not correctly formed. Please look into the version constraints.

Comment: I put it but it changed nothing i still have the same error

Comment: It seems like you have not correctly formed gemfile. Could you please add your gemfile contents as well?

Comment: source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem rake '11.1.2'
gem  'sqlite3'                                                                                                                                            #gem 'ZenTest'

Comment: Could you please add full content to your question. Also, could you also add the contents of `Gemfile.lock` file as well. This should give us everything we need to figure out the problem.

Comment: Ii add my gemfile.lock in my question, hop anyone can help me

Comment: I also wrote a comment. Please look into it.